# how to convert user friendly url to another url with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have one user friendly (`http://example.com/root1/root2?root3=abc25`) that I want to convert this to another url (`http://example.com/index.php?request=root1/root2?root3=abc25&root4=abcd`) 
this is my code when run this code I get this url (**`http://example.com/index.php?request=root1/root2`**)
I don't know where is my mistake please guide me about it.

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews

DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Rule should work by giving you query string as: `?request=root1/root2&root3=abc25` How are you testing it?

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite rule looks like standard fare for an MVC front controller. Are you using a framework by chance? In that case the answer lies with how the framework handles routing.

If you aren't using a framework, your *index.php* file will somehow have to determine what to do with a request for `http://example.com/index.php?request=root1/root2?root3=abc25&root4=abcd` in order to make it behave the same way `http://example.com/root1/root2?root3=abc25` does.

Comment: I don't use any framework and I want build my framework and use it.

Comment: Then you should study some of the other ones while you work on yours.